# Access web config in a separate js file

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-config

I need to read a web config key value from a js file. I know that we can just define a variable in aspx file and initialize it with an expression as below and then access this variable inside a js file. The js file is actually a part of custom dll referenced in the site

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   var CMSPopupAutoSize = 
       '<%=Convert.ToString(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FP:CMSPopupAutoSize"]) %>';

</script>
```

But my requirement is that i HAVE TO read the config file from inside js. I don't have to make any change in the existing site pages. its a sort of backward compatibility requirement.I found something related here http://forums.asp.net/t/1117176.aspx but didn't help.

Comment: :( doesn't help my case, i have already discussed that solution in the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible as such, as JS is not processed by the server when it's requested, but simply sent back in the response. What you could do though, is create an ashx handler that renders a JS file.

So, the idea would be to have a "almost javascript" file on your server. This file would be a special file containing mainly JS but aslo some server variables in it. You just have to decide of a format for those variables (for example `##APP_CMSPopupAutoSize##`).

Then, you would have to develop a handler (`ashx` file) to perform server-side treatment on this file. The handler would just read the file, identify variables and replace it with values coming from the web config, database, actually wherever you wish. The handler would then eventually render the modified string as a javascript file.

basically, in your HTML code, you would just have to call the handler that way :

```
<script src="/pathToHandler/myHandler.ashx"></script>
```

If I'm not mistaken, Microsoft implement this type of "server-side pre-processed JS" through the `WebResource.axd` handler.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't access your web.config directly from JS.

In your example, you pre-load a single value (`CMSPopupAutoSize`) from your web.config-settings. Could you not do something similar, but with a list or dictionary, or some similar structure instead?

This might be a slightly messy work-around, but should let you fetch several config values in a slightly more dynamic way, i.e. without requiring that each specific key is mapped into the page.

***Update*** *(partly in ref. to comments below)*: If you can't change anything on the page itself, perhaps you can create some other server-side resource (another page, or just a generated text-file that is publicly available?) from which the JS might be able to read? In any case, you have to find some way to expose your Config-values so JS can read them.

Being able to access the config file (or any other server side files) directly from JS would probably constitute a serious security threat.

Comment: yes i could do all that but i am not supposed to touch the asp.net website. just a key in web.config and use it in a js file :(

Comment: Can you just edit your answer with a link maybe which concludes that its not possible this way..

Comment: Then it's simply not possible... JS is not processed on the server and that's it, you can't access web.config from JS without a workaround, and any workaround would imply writing server-side code at some point. cfr my answer though... And there's no need to prove it, basic understanding of server-side and client-side concept is enough to understand this.

Comment: @Bartdude , thanks pro for your help. i need to postulate some other solution for this, even yours :)

Comment: @tariq I don't have any definitive guarantee, but I am fairly sure JS can not read/write anything serverside. See for example this thread and specific answer (by the OP himself): http://stackoverflow.com/a/19323572/336648

Answer (score 1):

Client Scripts cannot access web.config directly. Create a HttpHandler, call if from javascript and read web.config through the handler.

Comment: already proposed by Bartdude above, you should upvote him instead.