# File isn't Downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, yahoo-finance

I'm attempting to download a CSV file through Yahoo Finance with this code.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=snl1d1t1c1ohg&s=AAPL", function(data) {
            var output = data.split(new RegExp(",|\r")).map(function (element) {
                alert($.trim(element).toLowerCase());
                return $.trim(element).toLowerCase();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You can see I put the alert in there (for debugging purposes) but I'm not getting the alert. Is there something wrong with this code? (some of the code was taken from [how to create an array by reading text file in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846556/how-to-create-an-array-by-reading-text-file-in-javascript))

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4bQ7/1/) for easy edits/help.

Comment: I immediately received an error in my browser's console because of the same-origin policy. You can't make cross-domain AJAX requests so simply.

Comment: @Ian is there a way I can download a file with JS or should I use a server-side language?

Comment: @uofc I don't want to go to server-side languages just yet, I first want to make sure that it's impossible with a client-side script

Comment: You say "download" and then you say "read". Although they're similar, you really want to read the file, right? You want JavaScript to have access to its contents, right?

Comment: Yes @Ian, sorry about the confusion

Comment: @javadog36 I don't blame you, I tried it a long time ago, but the same origin is a tough one to get around. I posted a simple way to do it in php; all you would have to do is research how to handle files instead of just reading the page output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is blocked by same-origin policy.

Options:

- find other service that provides access to the data with [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or have [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORS) enabled for the data source.
- use server side proxy to read data

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll stick with a PHP script for now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out with php, you can tailor make it to suit your needs.

```
function queryphp($url)
{
    $portal = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($portal, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

    curl_setopt($portal, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    $output = curl_exec($portal); 
    if(!($output))
        header('Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/errorpage.php');

    curl_close($portal); 

    return $output;
}//example usage:
    //$page_data = queryphp("http://www.whatever.com/whateverpage.php[?var1=whatever&var2=whatever"]);
    //now you have the output from whateverpage.php saved as a string; which you can append anywhere to your current page's output. #repetitive code reduction
```

Comment: It's actually much easier to use file_get_contents if I were to go with PHP.